# Why Am I Getting Null Value in String Comparison

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, hashmap, duplicates

I have the code below that is supposed to find the duplicate strings as the user enters them so that I can remove the key from the map (I'm going to do that in future, for now, it's just about duplicate values in a string). However, I'm getting NullPointerException error in if statement. Why is this happening? Full code is below;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Testing
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        int i=0,j,k,map_addr;
        String [] inp_value = new String[100];
        String [] inp_addr_val = new String[100];
        String [] inp_addr = new String[100];
        String addr_path,sCurrentLine;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator map_iterator = map.keySet().iterator();


        System.out.println("Welcome! Please enter the addresses");

        while(i!=100)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter address:");
            inp_addr[i] = inp.nextLine();
            try 
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inp_addr[i]));

                while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                      inp_value[i]=reader.readLine();
                      inp_addr_val[i]=Integer.toString(i);
                      map.put(inp_addr_val[i],inp_value[i]);
                      i++;
                      System.out.println(map.get(inp_addr_val[i]));


                }
                         for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
                          {
                              if(inp_value[j].equals(inp_value[i]))
                              {
                              System.out.println("File already exists, skipping this file.");
                              i--;

                              }
                          }

            }catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Something bad happened. Program is exiting now...");
                System.exit(0);

            }





    }
    }}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Paste the stacktrace, please.

Comment: SO is not a debugging tool. Have you tried to debug the code by yourself?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for us to debug code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Testing
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        int i=0,j,k,map_addr;
        String [] inp_value = new String[100];
        String [] inp_addr_val = new String[100];
        String [] inp_addr = new String[100];
        String addr_path,sCurrentLine;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator map_iterator = map.keySet().iterator();


        System.out.println("Welcome! Please enter the addresses");

        while(i!=100)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter address:");
            inp_addr[i] = inp.nextLine();
            try 
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inp_addr[i]));

                while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                      inp_value[i]=reader.readLine();
                      inp_addr_val[i]=Integer.toString(i);
                      map.put(inp_addr_val[i],inp_value[i]);
                      i++;
                      System.out.println(map.get(inp_addr_val[i-1]));


                }
                         for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
                          {
                              if(inp_value[j].equals(inp_value[i-1]))
                              {
                              System.out.println("File already exists, skipping this file.");
                              i--;

                              }
                          }

            }catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                /*System.out.println("Something bad happened. Program is exiting now...");
                System.exit(0);*/

            }





    }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop change this statement `System.out.println(map.get(inp_addr_val[i]));` to `System.out.println(map.get(inp_addr_val[i-1]));`.

In your code actually you are trying to access the `i+1` variable which gives you NPE.

Comment: I think in that case it would just print "null"...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                          inp_value[i]=reader.readLine();
                          inp_addr_val[i]=Integer.toString(i);
                          map.put(inp_addr_val[i],inp_value[i]);
                          i++;
                          System.out.println(map.get(inp_addr_val[i]));
                    }
```

with:

```
while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                          inp_value[i]=sCurrentLine ;
                          inp_addr_val[i]=Integer.toString(i);
                          map.put(inp_addr_val[i],inp_value[i]);
                          i++;
                          System.out.println(map.get(inp_addr_val[i]));
                    }
```

Too simply explain yourproblem, you are checking if the Line you read is null and the insert the next line into the Array. So it mitght happen, that the last value of the array ist null.

Sarajog